# How to view attribute only in one store

Tags: attributes, store-view

How to view attribute only in one store?
My question is: How to Display attribute only in one store?
I have a multistore views. For example. How can I view dimension only on technical view but not for standart customers view?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a child theme for that store and with your themes layout xml file, add the attribute code.

So for example if I was to extend from the RWD theme and set "Color" not to be used on the product listing page I would do the following to display "Color" in my child theme.

**1. Add custom layout file**

```
<theme>
    <parent>rwd/default</parent>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <custom>
                <file>custom.xml</file>
            </custom>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</theme>
```

**2. Add Attribute**

Then in my custom.xml file, I would do the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_category_default>
        <reference name="product_list">
            <action method="addAttribute">
                <name>color</name>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Yes, it would be, but what if I have 500 attributes? And over time someone decides to make a difference? There is a possibility to do it from the administration?

Comment: Well 500 attributes would seem unlikely but there isn't an option in the Magento admin which would turn on/off a attribute per store view that I know of .  Even if you did have that option, in the example above I left out that you would have to update your template to get the value e.g. $product->getColor();